# Hooks and component re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

A component uses a hook. The hook changes it's state, the component gets re-rendered.

Here is an example that I found while learning how to create hooks.
The component has no state, the hook has some state. Whenever the hook's state changes, the component will re-render. How is the component flagged for re-rendering?
To me it looks as if no matter on which depth useState was called, it will always find the component that initiated the call and link it to the state.

The component
https://github.com/machadop1407/custom-use-fetch-hook-react/blob/main/src/App.js

The hook
https://github.com/machadop1407/custom-use-fetch-hook-react/blob/main/src/useFetch.js

Comment: sorry, what is your question?

Comment: Read about the life cycle methods of react you will get to know

Comment: biscuit765 - I have read it, can you share the link about hooks and re-rendering?
Horts - the question is, how the hook causes the control to rerender?

Comment: React re-renders the components whenever the state changes. State update is not immediate but React will try to execute it at the best possible moment. So if a state changes in a hook, and you use that hook in a component, the component will re-render.

Comment: Can we say like this? No matter on which depth useState was called, it will always find the component that initiated the call and link it to the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of the custom hook is part of the components state. With a custom hook you can think of its code being in the component that uses it.

Like:

```
const useCounter = () => {
  const [counter,setCounter] = useState(0);

  const incrementCounter = () => setCounter(counter+1);

  return [counter,incrementCounter];
}

export default function App() {
  const [counter,incrementCounter] = useCounter();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={incrementCounter}>{counter}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const incrementCounter = () => setCounter(counter + 1);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={incrementCounter}>{counter}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the following is a bad rule:

> No matter on which depth useState was called, it will always find the component that initiated the call and link it to the state

because there is no search for the state. Using a custom hook does not add any "depth" to a state. It is just a reorganisation of stateful code.

Comment: It is clearer now, thanks. When I was referring to depth, I was thinking about nested hooks

Comment: Welcome @whowhenhow, I guess you can then make me the answer to your question.